# Вывод строк столбца в переменной

Tags: oracle, plsql

Как можно сделать запрос, чтобы вывести строки по столбцу, название которого известно только после определения параметров, а именно имени таблицы и номера столбца?

```
DECLARE
   name_in    VARCHAR2(200) := 'DWH_gate.T$TERMINAL';
   number_in      NUMBER(30);
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
   select column_name into sql_stmt
   from all_tab_columns
   where table_name like upper(SUBSTR(name_in,instr(name_in,'.',1)+1))
   and owner like upper(REGEXP_SUBSTR(name_in,'[^.]+'))
   and column_id = 3;
```

Соответственно, по 3-ему столбцу таблицы `DWH_gate.T$TERMINAL` необходимо получить данные. Но также проблема в том, что неизвестно какой тип данных будет в столбце.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
declare
    type restyp is record (numcol number, datecol date, charcol varchar2(128));
    res restyp;
    tabnam varchar2(200) := 'hr.employees';
    colnum int := 3;
    colnam varchar2 (32);
    coltyp varchar2 (8);
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    select column_name, data_type into colnam, coltyp
    from all_tab_columns
    where owner||'.'||table_name = upper (tabnam)
    and column_id = colnum;
    open rc for 
        ' select '||colnam||
        ' from   '||tabnam||
        ' order by 1 fetch first 3 rows only';
    dbms_output.put_line (colnam||chr(10)||'-----------------');   
    loop
        case coltyp when 'VARCHAR2' then 
            fetch rc into res.charcol;
        end case;
        exit when rc%notfound;
        case coltyp when 'VARCHAR2' then 
            dbms_output.put_line (res.charcol);
        end case;
    end loop;    
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
LAST_NAME
-----------------
Abel
Ande
Atkinson
```

---

Но лучше будет вeрнуть открытый курсор, его получатель может всегда определить тип колонки по описанию курсора. Например, IDE (SQL Developer, SQL*Plus и т.д.) сами выполнят логику `loop ... case ... fetch ...` из примера выше, и выведут результат из переменной подстановки `rc`:

```
var rc refcursor
declare
    tabnam varchar2(200) := 'hr.employees';
    colnum int := 3;
    colnam varchar2 (32);
begin
    select column_name into colnam
    from all_tab_columns
    where owner||'.'||table_name = upper (tabnam)
    and column_id = colnum;
    open :rc for 
        ' select '||colnam||
        ' from   '||tabnam||
        ' order by 1 fetch first 3 rows only'; 
end;
/
```

Comment: Добрый день.
Спасибо большое за ответ. Не могли бы Вы объяснить, у меня почему-то pl sql ругается на первую строчку.... в связи с чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Первая строка PL/SQL - declare, в чём там может быть ошибка?

Comment: Ругается на курсор var rc refcursor....

Comment: Это не PL/SQL, это переменная подстановки, которая создаётся в IDE, где  вы работаете. К вашему вопросу она никакого отношения не имеет, я использовал её только, чтобы показать, что пример рабочий и вывести результат.

Comment: Понял. А не подскажите, как можно вывести данный блок без курсора?
    open :rc for 
        ' select '||colnam||
        ' from   '||tabnam||
        ' order by 1 fetch first 3 rows only';

Comment: А в каком виде вам нужен вывод?

Comment: Мне нужны просто все строки столбца, который задается переменными. Это всегда какой-то один столбец, но тип данных в столбце может быть абсолютно разным. По сути то, что в Вашем примере подходит

Comment: подправил немного Ваш скрипт, но почему-то никакого результата не выдает, скорее всего что-то не так с курсором сделал:
declare
    tabnam varchar2(200) := 'DWH_gate.T$TERMINAL';
    colnum int := 3;
    colnam varchar2 (32);
    TYPE var_cur_type IS REF CURSOR; 
    var_cur var_cur_type;
    --number rc refcursor;
begin
    select column_name into colnam
    from all_tab_columns
    where owner||'.'||table_name = upper (tabnam)
    and column_id = colnum;
    open var_cur for 
        ' select '||colnam||
        ' from   '||tabnam||
        ' order by 1';  
end;

Comment: Тогда не совсем понял, а что тогда не устраивает? Курсор содержит все строки столбца и их тип может быть любым. Может вы не можете с курсорами работать? Какой у вас ожидаемый результат?

Comment: Да, с курсорами почти не приходилось работать, отсюда и проблемы. Результат хотел бы видеть просто столбец, который задавался бы по определенным параметрам....

Comment: Хорошо, вот ваша [попытка из комментария выше](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8a9200ee8a6e509f6934a9430d6009a). Что там не устраивает?

Comment: В том запросе ничего не выводится почему-то,хотя столбец высчитывается верно,но вывод всего запроса пустой

Comment: Вообщем, не совсем понял, что ожидается в результате. Вы его должны чётко себе представить, до того как задать вопрос.  _Результат хотел бы видеть просто столбец, который задавался бы по определенным параметрам_, а что в ответе не просто столбец, или не тот столбец, или что с  ним не так?

Comment: _В том запросе ничего не выводится почему-то_, ну почему, это же очевидно - вы ничего и не пытаетесь вывести. Посмотрите, я поправил пример, это то что вы ожидали?

Comment: Для вашего понимания, PL/SQL программа выполняется на сервере, она никогда ничего не выводила, и выводить не будет, она только обрабатывает данные.

Comment: Опять не то?  Так в каком же виде вам нужен вывод?

Comment: Я очень сильно упростил Ваш запрос, по сути мне нужно вывести результат следующего запроса:declare
    res varchar2(200);
    tabnam varchar2(200) := 'DWH_gate.T$TERMINAL';
    colnum int := 3;
    colnam varchar2 (32) := 'ID_AGENT';
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||colnam||' from DWH_gate.T$TERMINAL' into res;
    dbms_output.put_line (res);
end;
но тут нужен курсор, как я понимаю, т.к. вывод подразумевает несколько строк

Comment: Не следует помещать код в комментарий, я его не могу читать. Поместите его на [фиддл](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8a9200ee8a6e509f6934a9430d6009a) и дайте ссылку. Мне кажется, вам надо задать новый вопрос, тк этот вопрос полностью отвечен и то, что вы сейчас пытаетесь выяснить, с ним никак не связано.

Comment: Да, хорошо, так и сделал